# Get local users from Mac and Linux machines

Tags: python, linux, macos, network-programming

I created a python script to a while to retrieve all the local users of windows machines on my network. I used the win32net library. I now need to do this for Mac and Linux machines. I have have been search for a while now and still have nothing but a long list of Mac and Linux user groups that meet around my house. Does anyone have a suggested library to look into?

Comment: Will this run on the machine locally, or are you connecting remotely and running it?

Answer (score 5):

I think your best bet is to use **POSIX** standard interface, e.g. [getent](http://linux.die.net/man/1/getent) via http://pypi.python.org/pypi/getent/0.1 package

`getent.passwd()` should work pretty much analogous to [getpwent](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/getpwent.3.html) system call.

**EDIT**: If you are doing this remotely it probably means that you can't install python packages on the hosts, so you might just want to read the contents of `/etc/passwd` and parse it. Something like (assuming you have the `ssh` command in path and you have set up [public key authentication](https://hkn.eecs.berkeley.edu/~dhsu/ssh_public_key_howto.html)):

```
import subprocess
users = []
p = subprocess.Popen(['ssh','<host name or ip address>','cat /etc/passwd'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
passwd = p.stdout.readlines()
for line in passwd:
    fields = line.split(':')
    uid = int(fields[2])
    if uid > 500 and uid < 32328
         users.append(fields[0])
print users
```